# WPF set Toggle Button Ischecked Programmatically

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a wpf mvvm app with DataGrid bound to DataView. One of the columns contains a Toggle button. The IsChecked property is not bound to a valuew in the DataView row but based on a code behind and is binded to a bool property of the ViewModel.
The problem: when I set the property to "true", the Checked event is fired. Is there a way to avoid this event from being fired?
I'm very new to WPF so perhaps I'm on the wrong track here.

The XAML:

```
  <ToggleButton Content="{x:Static resx:IVFOocytes.PartOfGroup}"  
   IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.ToggleStrawSpecificIsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
      Checked="ToggleStrawSpecificTrue_Click" 
      Unchecked="ToggleStrawSpecificFalse_Click" Margin = "0,0,10,0"
      Width="150" HorizontalAlignment = "Center" />
```

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the binding `Mode`?, Maybe `Mode=OneWay` might do it.

Comment: First http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13638.troubleshooting-wpf-debugging-wpf.aspx also, we don't even know if you're implementing INPC, or if you're doing it correctly.  So who knows?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear, I'm not getting execption, I have unwanted behavior but I guess that's how it works. I found a workeround for this issue, question can be closed.

Comment: Of course the checked event is fired. That's the whole point of it. You're definitely on the wrong track if you think you need to set the checkbox to true but ignore the checked event. You need to explain what you are REALLY trying to do.